# Errors installing rgdal on LINUX system?

Tags: r, installation, rgdal

I am trying to install rgdal on a Linux cluster, but am running into some issues. I have successfully installed gdal and proj4, but when I try to build rgdal, I receive the message that "proj_api.h not found in standard or given locations". proj_api.h is located at /bin/proj4/include/proj_api.h. I have added the path to $PATH, however I still can't compile it.

How can I specify the path so that I can install rgdal?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248815/rgdal-package-installation

Comment: The answer that you provide the link to is not viable in my case because I am unable to use apt-get, yum, brew, etc. to install applications. My guess is that I need to provide the link to proj4 to rgdal when trying to install, but not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 4):

I modified my code to provide links to proj_api.h. Here it is.

```
install.packages("rgdal",lib="./R_Packages",method="curl", configure.args = c("--with-proj-include=/p/home/bin/proj4/include","--with-proj-lib=/p/home/bin/proj4/lib"))
```